# css sibling limited to parent object

Tags: html, css, rating, siblings

I've got the following issue, with a star rating css example. It's not working when more then one fieldset is added.

```css
 fieldset.star {
  box-sizing:border-box;
  width: -moz-fit-content;
  width: -webkit-fit-content;
  width: fit-content;
  position:relative; 
  margin: 10px auto 10px auto;
 }

 fieldset.star.star5 > label:nth-of-type(even){
  display:none;
 }

 fieldset.star > input[type="radio"] {
  display: none;
 }

 fieldset.star > label {
  display:inline-block;
  float:right;
  color:rgba(255,255,255,.5);
 }

 fieldset.star > label:before {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 4rem;
  padding: .3rem .2rem;
  margin: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  content: "\f005 "; /* full star */ 
 }

 fieldset.star .half{
  color:rgba(255,255,255,.1);
 }

 fieldset.star .half:before {
  content: "\f089 "; /* half star no outline */
  position: absolute;
  padding-right: 0;
 }
 /* Click + hover color */
 fieldset.star > input:checked ~ label, /* color current and previous stars on checked */
 fieldset.star > label:hover, 
 fieldset.star > label:hover ~ label { 
  color: #DDBB00;  
 } /* color previous stars on hover */

 /* Hover highlights */
 fieldset.star > input:checked + label:hover, 
 fieldset.star > input:checked ~ label:hover, /* highlight current and previous stars */
 fieldset.star > input:checked ~ label:hover ~ label, /* highlight previous selected stars for new rating */
 fieldset.star > label:hover ~ input:checked ~ label /* highlight previous selected stars */ { 
  color: #FFD700;  
 }
```

```html
 <fieldset class="star">
  <input type="radio" id="rating10" name="answer" value="10"><label for="rating10"></label>
  <input type="radio" id="rating9" name="answer" value="9"><label class="half" for="rating9"></label>
  <input type="radio" id="rating8" name="answer" value="8"><label for="rating8"></label>
  <input type="radio" id="rating7" name="answer" value="7"><label class="half" for="rating7"></label>
  <input type="radio" id="rating6" name="answer" value="6"><label for="rating6"></label>
  <input type="radio" id="rating5" name="answer" value="5"><label class="half" for="rating5"></label>
  <input type="radio" id="rating4" name="answer" value="4"><label for="rating4"></label>
  <input type="radio" id="rating3" name="answer" value="3"><label class="half" for="rating3"></label>
  <input type="radio" id="rating2" name="answer" value="2"><label for="rating2"></label>
  <input type="radio" id="rating1" name="answer" value="1"><label class="half" for="rating1"></label>
 </fieldset>
 <fieldset class="star">
  <input type="radio" id="rating110" name="answer" value="10"><label for="rating110"></label>
  <input type="radio" id="rating19" name="answer" value="9"><label class="half" for="rating19"></label>
  <input type="radio" id="rating18" name="answer" value="8"><label for="rating18"></label>
  <input type="radio" id="rating17" name="answer" value="7"><label class="half" for="rating17"></label>
  <input type="radio" id="rating16" name="answer" value="6"><label for="rating16"></label>
  <input type="radio" id="rating15" name="answer" value="5"><label class="half" for="rating15"></label>
  <input type="radio" id="rating14" name="answer" value="4"><label for="rating14"></label>
  <input type="radio" id="rating13" name="answer" value="3"><label class="half" for="rating13"></label>
  <input type="radio" id="rating12" name="answer" value="2"><label for="rating12"></label>
  <input type="radio" id="rating11" name="answer" value="1"><label class="half" for="rating11"></label>
 </fieldset>
```

Combined with this css, it works great,but not when there are more of the same elements [fieldset]. I can't find the right answer for this, but I want this to work out properly. I know i can use javascript/jquery [plugins] for this but I want to use this css solution if it's possible

Does someome have some thoughts?

Comment: In what way isn't it working?

Comment: give the second set of radios a different name - answer1 or something like that - they are not all for the same thing as the first set of radios so they should have a different name

Comment: @Pete is right - and if you are requiring them have the same `name` then you would have to put them in the same `fieldset.star`

Comment: @Pete Thanks, the solution is making use of different input names. Why did I miss that 

Answer (score 0):

Each set of `fieldsets` should have a different name.

```css
fieldset.star {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: -moz-fit-content;
  width: -webkit-fit-content;
  width: fit-content;
  position: relative;
  margin: 10px auto 10px auto;
}

fieldset.star.star5>label:nth-of-type(even) {
  display: none;
}

fieldset.star>input[type="radio"] {
  display: none;
}

fieldset.star>label {
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .5);
}

fieldset.star>label:before {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 4rem;
  padding: .3rem .2rem;
  margin: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  content: "\f005 ";
  /* full star */
}

fieldset.star .half {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .1);
}

fieldset.star .half:before {
  content: "\f089 ";
  /* half star no outline */
  position: absolute;
  padding-right: 0;
}


/* Click + hover color */

fieldset.star>input:checked~label,

/* color current and previous stars on checked */

fieldset.star>label:hover,
fieldset.star>label:hover~label {
  color: #DDBB00;
}


/* color previous stars on hover */


/* Hover highlights */

fieldset.star>input:checked+label:hover,
fieldset.star>input:checked~label:hover,

/* highlight current and previous stars */

fieldset.star>input:checked~label:hover~label,

/* highlight previous selected stars for new rating */

fieldset.star>label:hover~input:checked~label
/* highlight previous selected stars */

{
  color: #FFD700;
}
```

```html
<fieldset class="star">
  <input type="radio" id="rating10" name="answer" value="10"><label for="rating10"></label>
  <input type="radio" id="rating9" name="answer" value="9"><label class="half" for="rating9"></label>
  <input type="radio" id="rating8" name="answer" value="8"><label for="rating8"></label>
  <input type="radio" id="rating7" name="answer" value="7"><label class="half" for="rating7"></label>
  <input type="radio" id="rating6" name="answer" value="6"><label for="rating6"></label>
  <input type="radio" id="rating5" name="answer" value="5"><label class="half" for="rating5"></label>
  <input type="radio" id="rating4" name="answer" value="4"><label for="rating4"></label>
  <input type="radio" id="rating3" name="answer" value="3"><label class="half" for="rating3"></label>
  <input type="radio" id="rating2" name="answer" value="2"><label for="rating2"></label>
  <input type="radio" id="rating1" name="answer" value="1"><label class="half" for="rating1"></label>
</fieldset>
<fieldset class="star">
  <input type="radio" id="rating110" name="answer1" value="10"><label for="rating110"></label>
  <input type="radio" id="rating19" name="answer1" value="9"><label class="half" for="rating19"></label>
  <input type="radio" id="rating18" name="answer1" value="8"><label for="rating18"></label>
  <input type="radio" id="rating17" name="answer1" value="7"><label class="half" for="rating17"></label>
  <input type="radio" id="rating16" name="answer1" value="6"><label for="rating16"></label>
  <input type="radio" id="rating15" name="answer1" value="5"><label class="half" for="rating15"></label>
  <input type="radio" id="rating14" name="answer1" value="4"><label for="rating14"></label>
  <input type="radio" id="rating13" name="answer1" value="3"><label class="half" for="rating13"></label>
  <input type="radio" id="rating12" name="answer1" value="2"><label for="rating12"></label>
  <input type="radio" id="rating11" name="answer1" value="1"><label class="half" for="rating11"></label>
</fieldset>
```